# Can I make a text box in SSRS disappear, shrink, or otherwise "roll up" if there's no data?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have several text boxes containing calculated data. Many of them will often be null or zero. How can I save space by making them go away unless there's something to show?

Comment: Can you post an image of the layout of your report

Comment: If the whole row or column is empty then you can hide it. You can also hide individual textboxes but there will still be the gap where it used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the text box and click `Text Box Properties`. Click `Visibility` from the list on the left, then choose `Show or hide based on an expression`. Then click the `fx` button to bring up the expression editor. Below is an example expression that will hide the text box if its value is NULL or 0.

```
=IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Test2.Value, "DataSet1")) OR Sum(Fields!Test2.Value, "DataSet1") = 0
```

[image]